# Express with Handlebars will not load data into variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a NodeJS/Express app that is using Handlebars for templates.

All of the templates and partials load fine except where I am returning data from an Express API.

The data is returned and I can see it in the Chrome debugger.

In this template, I am defining the HTML in a script and compiling it in JS.

Here is the template HTML:

```
<script id="search-result-template" type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div>String</div>
  {{#each patient}}
    <div>
    {{cp_first_name}}
    </div>
    {{!-- {{> searchresultpartial}} --}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

The actual page is quite a bit more structured but I've narrowed it down to this for debugging.

Here is the code that compiles the template:

```
let patientSearchButton = document.getElementById('patient-search-execute');
patientSearchButton.addEventListener("click", async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let patientSearchFirstname = document.getElementById('patient-search-firstname')
    let cp_first_name = patientSearchFirstname.value;
    let url = baseURL + 'patientsearchquery/' + cp_first_name;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    var data = response.json();
    let patientList = await data;
    patient = patientList;

    if (response.status === 200) {
         let patientSearchResultTemplate = document.querySelector("#search-result-template").innerHTML;
        let patientSearchResultTemplateFunction = Handlebars.compile(patientSearchResultTemplate);
        let patientSearchResultTemplateObject = patientSearchResultTemplateFunction(patient);
        let contentPartial = document.getElementById('patient-search-table');
        contentPartial.innerHTML = patientSearchResultTemplateObject;

        if (Handlebars.Utils.isArray(patient)) {
            console.log("Array");
        } else {
            console.log("Not");
        }
        console.log(patient);
    } else {
        alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
    }
});
```

I can see the data from the API and I'm verifying that Handlebars sees it as an Array.

It seems to break when it enters the #each helper.

I've tried to shift the context with ../ and I've tried every variation I can think of the coax the data into the template.

I was concerned that being in an event handler tied to a button click, that the "this" context was breaking.  I moved the code outside of the event handler and "this" seemed to be correct in Chrome but the behavior did not change.

Here is the array data in Chrome:
[image: array data in chrome]

When paused on a breakpoint in Chrome, I can see that the patient data is present when being passed to the template.

I know it's something dumb but my head hurts from banging it against the wall.

This has happened on two different templates.  Granted, they were similar, but I've tried numerous variations and it still isn't loading.

Thanks for any help you might offer.

Does anybody see anything obvious?

Addendum:

I changed the code to pass the property and I can see it in Chrome now.
[image: array with patients property]

It still doesn't show up in Handlebars.

this.patients shows the data in the console.  Why won't it render the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{#each patient}}` in your template anticipates that the data that you pass to your template function has a property named `patient` and that the value of this property is iterable - like an Array.

However, it appears that you are simply passing an Array directly to your template function, and that Array does not have a `patient` property, and so the `#each` loop never executes.

One way to make this work would be to pass an Object to your template function  and to assign to that Object a key, `patient`, with its value being your Array of patients.

This would require changing:

```
let patientSearchResultTemplateObject = patientSearchResultTemplateFunction(patient);
```

to:

```
let patientSearchResultTemplateObject = patientSearchResultTemplateFunction({ patient: patient });
```

Or use the shorthand:

```
let patientSearchResultTemplateObject = patientSearchResultTemplateFunction({ patient });
```

Note: As `patient` is an Array of Patient Objects, if I were on your team, I would urge you to add an "s" to its name to make it plural.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I changed the code to both ({ patients: patients}) and just ({ patients}).  I can now see the patient property in Chrome.  Handlebars still does not see the variable.  Oh, and I did pluralize it.

Comment: @TexEvans: Have you updated your template as well? `{{#each patient}}` expects a property named "patient".

Comment: Oh, yeah.  I tried {{#each patients}} with {{cp_first_name}} and {{#each patients}} with {{patients.cp_first_name}} and {{#each patients}} with {{this.cp_first_name}} and {{#each this.patients}} with {{cp_first_name}} and probably several other things as well.  The data is in the document scope so I don't see why Handlebars is treating it like a cold sore.  I have vars returning from api calls in other places on the site without a problem but these two pages have something odd about them.  I just can't find it.

Comment: @TexEvans: I am quite sure that `{{#each patients}}` with `{{cp_first_name}}` is correct. You might want to try logging your `patients` array from your template function to see what Handlebars thinks the value of `patients` is with `{{log patients}}`.

Comment: I am thinking the problem stems from the fact that I have express-handlebars installed in express and handlebars.js loaded on the page.  When i register a helper to see the context in the .js for the page, where the template is compiled and data loaded, the helper returns 'undefined'.  When I register the same helper in the app.js file, it shows information from express-handlebars and does not show patients in locals.  At the same time, Chrome does show patients in locals.

Comment: That is a different problem. Client-side and server-side are completely separate execution contexts. A helper registered on one is not going to be available to the other without some work to make it available to both and registered with both.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure how to get the logging into the template function.  It doesn't seem like patients exists in the template.  When I do {{#if patients}} in the template, it skips right over it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you. One guess: Could there be more to your template than you have shared? Is perhaps `patients` nested in another evaluation context and so out-of-scope where you call `#each`?

Comment: You've given me some good insight.  I appreciate it.  It has to be a context issue so I'll go back through it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the problem was that the data was seen Handlebars as a Sequelizer Object.  It was unable to access the prototype due to a security update in Handlebars 4.6.0.

Rather than using "allowInsecurePrototypeAccess" which is a widely suggested fix but one that seems like unsound advice, I made a deep copy of the data by using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() and Handlebars was able to access it.

It was a context error, just not the one I was expecting.